# Html.EditorFor valor Default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como poderia colocar valor Default em um `Html.EditorFor` ?

Entendendo meu código,

Tenho um campo que é um filtro quando clica no `EditorFor` abre o calendário, Gostaria que aparecesse o `datetime.now` mas apenas visual sem efetuar o filtro.

Pois se eu colocar no model (get;set) consigo mostrar mais já efetuando o filtro.

Código usado.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores)
```

Já tentei assim.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = ViewBag.DataAtual} })

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores, new { @Value = ViewBag.DataAtual})
```

Alguem conhece uma forma de passar o um valor default?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, é algo [como isso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ydLHSn) que você quer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode alterar a propriedade `model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores` para:

```
private DateTime? _dataInicioIndicadores;
public DateTime dataInicioIndicadores
{
    get
    {
        if(_dataInicioIndicadores.HasValue)
            return _dataInicioIndicadores.Value;
        else
            return DateTime.Now;
    }
    set
    {
        _dataInicioIndicadores = value;
    }
}
```

ou simplesmente atribuir o valor na controller:

```
if(!model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores.HasValue)
{
    model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores = DateTime.Now
}
```

e caso a dataInicioIndicadores não seja Nullable (DateTime?)

```
if(!model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores = DateTime.Now
}
```

Atenciosamente,
Igor Quirino

Comment: Igor.! Obrigado, Atribui na controller e fez exatamente o que queria!

Answer (score 2):

`EditorFor` não vai funcionar porque `EditorFor` precisa intuir o tipo para gerar o campo. Por precaução, retiraram a possibilidade do `EditorFor` receber valor porque isso seria uma fonte infinita de bugs.

Agora, a seguinte construção funciona:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelPaging.Filter.dataInicioIndicadores, new { @Value = ViewBag.DataAtual })
```

Comment: Cigado,! Valeu pela resposta, eu já tinha tentado com textbox mais ela não aparecia o calendário. segui o que o Igor falou e resolveu o problema.!

Comment: Como assim, "não aparecia o calendário"?

Comment: Quando uso Html.EditorFor e sua propriedade for do tipo DateTime ele mostra um calendário do JQuery,

Comment: O jQuery UI datepicker? Isto não tem nada a ver com o que você perguntou. Aliás, é bastante simples de configurar o datepicker tanto pra `EditorFor` quanto pra `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: Sim, Pois se eu abri o Jquery e tentar localizar EditorFor não encontra, pois tentei fazer isso antes de tudo.
Sou iniciante não fui muito ao fundo no Jquery apenas traduzir o calendário para PT-BR, se poder colocar onde posso ir para poder configurar eu agradeço, não precisa colocar o codigo todo mais só onde é mais ou menos.

Comment: Na verdade, em navegadores novos existem alguns recursos como:
<input type="date"/> quando o EditorFor identifica uma data ele coloca type="date" e o próprio navegador mostra um DatePicker, sem necessidade de plugins ou algo do gênero.
Se o navegador for antigo ele mostra um textbox comum.

Comment: Segue exemplo: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date